# Laravel Validation : How to validate two related foreign key correspond or not

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I have student, grade and section table. Section belongs to grade. Student belongs to grade and section. Now when student has to be created, I get grade id and section id. I want to validate the section id if the section id belongs to same grade id as in request.

grade table : id, title.
section table : id, grade_id, title.
student table : id, name, grade_id, section_id, ....

Answer: 'exists:sections,id,grade_id,' . $this->input("grade_id")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use a validation rule as follows:

```php
'section_id' => "exists:<section table name>,id,grade_id,{$request->get('grade_id'}"
```

Comment: first with section id after table name gave error since there is no column of name section_id in section table. then i edited to just 'id'. now the validation fails even if there is section id for that grade id.

Comment: I have edited the suggestion. Please make the changes as necessary.

Comment: this is exactly what i have edited and tested. With this validation fails even if there is section id for that grade id.

Comment: can you verify `$request->get('grade_id')` is giving you the submitted grade ID value? If you are validating with FormRequest class, you can do `$this->input('grade_id')`. Also verify `grade_id` is the correct attribute name for the variable you are expecting.

Comment: Thanks it was a form request and it worked. 
     exists:sections,id,grade_id,' . $this->input("grade_id")